# How to show standard editor statusbar items for MultiPageEditor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When I open a file in a TextEditor the status bar shows information like positions, whether the file is writable or not ...

Now I have created a MultiPageEditor that contains a class derived from org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor. If I edit a file with this editor the status bar remains empty.

Is there an easy way make the standard status bar items visible if the TextEditor is embedded in a MultiPageEditor?

Im using Eclipse Kepler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `MultiPageEditorActionBarContributor` class you need to do:

```java
private StatusLineContributionItem _showLine;

...

_showLine = new StatusLineContributionItem(ITextEditorActionConstants.STATUS_CATEGORY_INPUT_POSITION, true, 14);


@Override
public void setActivePage(IEditorPart part)
{
  if (part instanceof ITextEditorExtension)
   {
     ITextEditorExtension extension = (ITextEditorExtension)part;

     extension.setStatusField(_showLine, ITextEditorActionConstants.STATUS_CATEGORY_INPUT_POSITION);
   }
}


@Override
public void contributeToStatusLine(IStatusLineManager statusLineManager)
{
  statusLineManager.add(_showLine);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Greg. That's exactly what I was searching for.